# Erlang: Returning a variable (gb_trees) from a function call?

Tags: tree, erlang, return, return-value

I'm trying to return the variable `Tree` in the code but it seems as though Erlang doesn't have return variable explicitly set. I want to run the code from the shell like this:

```
3> {Pid,Tree} = gbtree:start().
{<0.41.0>,init}
4> 
4> gbtree:add_entry(2,Pid,Tree). 
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    gb_trees:is_defined(2,init) (gb_trees.erl, line 221)
     in function  gb_trees:enter/3 (gb_trees.erl, line 335)
     in call from gbtree:add_entry/3 (gbtree.erl, line 13)
```

Notice the error relates to the `Tree` not getting passed correctly into `gbtree:add_entry(Key,Val,Tree).`. Doing this differently however does work from the shell. The function call `gbtree:start().` should return something like `{<#.#.#>,{0,nil}}`.

```
2> Tree = gb_trees:empty().   
{0,nil}
3>   
3> gbtree:add_entry(1,"something",Tree).
gbt_r lookup 1 "something"
 {1,{1,"something",nil,nil}}
```

The following is the test code gbtree.erl

```
-module(gbtree).
-export([start/0, init/0, add_entry/3]).

start() ->  
    register(?MODULE, Pid = spawn(?MODULE, Tree = init, [])),
        { Pid, Tree}.

init() ->   
    Tree = gb_trees:empty(),
    Tree.

add_entry(Key, Data, Tree1) ->
    Tree2 = gb_trees:enter( Key, Data, Tree1),
    io:format("gbt_r lookup ~p ~p~n ",[Key, Data]),
    Tree2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in function start(), when you spawn the new process, you pass module name ?MODULE, function name 'init'  and parameters []. But when you do that, you specify that variable Tree is equal to second parameter, - atom 'init'.

It means return value from  function start() will be tuple with process id and atom 'init'.  (not the result of init function).

Speaking franlky I don't quite understand why you use process here, So , I'd make this module this way:

```
-module(gbtree).
-export([init/0, add_entry/3]).

init() -> gb_trees:empty().

add_entry(Key, Data, Tree1) ->
    Tree2 = gb_trees:enter( Key, Data, Tree1),
    io:format("gbt_r lookup ~p ~p~n ",[Key, Data]),
    Tree2.
```

and use it:

```
T = gbtree:init(),

T1 = gbtree:add_entry(2,this_is_data,T).
```